# Find a common values in array of objects and organize them

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a problem with figuring out how to find a common values in array of objects.
I have a big array of objects and every 2 objects have the same `transactionHash`. I need to find those objects that have the same values and put them in one array.

```
[
  [{...otherData, transactionHash: 1}, {...otherData, transactionHash: 1}]
  [{...otherData, transactionHash: 2}, {...otherData, , transactionHash: 2}]
]
```

I need it to be returned just like that!

I tried to reduce the array:

```
return yourData.reduce(function(curr, x) {
    (curr[x[key]] = curr[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return curr;
})
```

And surprisingly I got most of the data back organized but somehow the last object wasn't in the right place but the object with the same `transactionHash` exists.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass an initial value for `curr` -

```
return yourData.reduce(function(curr, x) {
    (curr[x[key]] = curr[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return curr;
}, {});
```

If you don't, then the first element of `yourData` will be used as the initial value.